# How to upload a file on Windows Desktop App using Appium?

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, appium

During writing python autotests for Windows Desktop Application on C# I faced with a problem:
The app has a button "Browse" that open file explorer, so we can select and upload some files and the app will process it.
But how we can do this by autotests?

In selenium (with web apps) when we want to upload a file we need smth like:

```
self.session.find_element_by_name("Browse").send_keys(r"C:/directory/file_for_upload.txt" + Keys.Enter)
```

But this selenium example doesn't work for Windows Desktop Application.
And device android functions like pull/push that are in the appium documentation obviously doesn't work too.

Are there other ways to upload file into Windows Desktop Application?
Help, please)

Comment: appium is not proper tool for testing windows applications. you have to use other tools to test it and perform such tasks.

Comment: hmmm, but appium supports the creation of autotests for Windows Desktop Apps... And further, I need to create Android set of autotests... That's why I select this tool)

Comment: This is my fault, the testing app represents open file dialog, so, we can connect to this file dialog very easily.